# Some elements going on next line on Bootstrap SM Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I wanna have a row that all of my elements stay in same row. this is my code and buttons goes to next line on SM size (less than 576 px). how can i fix it?
please look at the screen shot.
[3 buttons goes next line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Qxl.jpg)

```
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                <img src="img/1.png" alt="site-logo" class="site-logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-7 d-none d-md-block">
                <label class="sr-only"></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5 col-md-3 header-btn ml-auto">
                <button class="btn btn-header d-md-none">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn">ورود</button>
                <button class="btn">ثبت نام</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code, most of which have to do with your use of `col-xs`.  The first problem is that based on the rest of your code you're using Bootstrap 4, which removed the `-xs` suffix.

Even if you were on Bootstrap 3 though, there is no `-0` grid size.  The smallest valid numeral would be `1`, so by using `0` you're effectively forcing Bootstrap to ignore those invalid column declarations until it hits a valid one, which in the case of your 2nd column would be `col-md-7`.

So first we need to correct your column declarations.  The other issue you might run into is your `d-*-*` declarations.  In Bootstrap 3 it using `d-block` was the *right* way to make a column visible again... but in Bootstrap 4 you need to use `d-*-flex` because Columns are part of the Flexbox model now.  If you rely on `-block` you change the behavior of the column (from Flex to Block level element).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <img src="img/1.png" alt="site-logo" class="site-logo">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-7 d-none d-md-flex">
    <label class="sr-only"></label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-md-3 header-btn ml-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-header d-md-none"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    <button class="btn">ورود</button>
    <button class="btn">ثبت نام</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only other changes here are some revisions to your column sizing; you really should try to have your columns always add up to `12` if you intend the content to span the full width of your `container`.